# Writing buffer to BYTE* using CURL

Tags: visual-c++, libcurl

How to write a request buffer to a variable of type BYTE*? I have alreay tried the write own func CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION - https://pastebin.com/UBrp7Wyx and set the CURLOPT_WRITEDATA to

```
BYTE* raw_data = nullptr;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &raw_data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, why you need to store BYTE type? If you want to use CURL for websites and want to accept some extended symbols (like cyrillic), you will not get expected behaviour (for example, UTF-8 has backward compatibility with ASCII, so simple `reinterpret` or +128 to each symbol will not help). It will have same behaviour as if you converting some `char` buffer to something else.

So code like this with simple `char`s work fine:

```
...

// yours write_function
size_t curlWriteFunc(char* data, size_t size, size_t nmemb,  std::string* buffer)
{
    size_t result = 0;

    if (buffer != NULL)
    {
        buffer->append(data, size * nmemb);
        result = size * nmemb;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
   ... // some prepares, setting up easy_handler and so on

   std::string buffer;

   // set up write function and pointer to buffer
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &curlWriteFunc);
   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buffer);

   ... // make request and other things
}
```

However, if you are using `CURL` not for websites but for own client, which recives some binary data and `BYTE` is required, you will have to use some own `struct` which contains `BYTE *`, controls allocated size and reallocate memory if needed... Or just use `vector<BYTE>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure to accumulate data as it comes in, a `std::string` suffices for that.

At the end, you can then simply do: (assuming you have a `std::string s`)

```
BYTE * raw_data = (BYTE *)s.data();
```

Note that the `raw_data` pointer is only valid for as long as the string is alive. If you need to contents to survive for longer than that, use a heap allocation and memcpy:

```
BYTE * raw_data = new BYTE[s.size()];
memcpy(raw_data, s.data(), s.size());
```

Note that you need to `delete[] raw_data` yourself at some point.